# Can I initially retrieve x number of records, and then every new record going forward with AngularFire?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to initially retrieve the first `x` number of records from my firebase with AngularFire, I know I can limit the number of records with a query: `var query = ref.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(myNumber);`. However, this also makes it so any new records bump out older records on the client. I want to retrieve a certain number of records, and going forward recieve every new record.

I am not sure how I would go about doing this using the `$firebaseArray` object as it automatically appends and remove records, the behavior of which seems to be abstracted away.

Edit: I would like to avoid appending the first x# of records to a separate array and than appending that to the `ngRepeat` is at all possible.

Edit2: It looks like I could make a new firebaseArray with a query for the last xx records, take the first record of that array and make a new query with `.startAt(myIdentifier)` and go from there. The issue with that is that it's async, which is a pain to handle.